# Angular: Dynamically generated FormArray with a large number of FormGroups as members makes the page unresponsive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have a dynamically constructed `FormArray` which is generated by the below code.

```
this.priceListForm.addControl('priceListLines', this.formBuilder.array(this.priceListDetails.priceListLines.map(item => this.buildPriceListItem(item.listLinesId, item.prn, item.price, item.currencyCode, item.startDateActive, item.endDateActive)), dateConflictsValidator));
```

`priceListDetails.priceListLines` is an array of JSON objects and I'm mapping them to be `FormGroup`s using `buildPriceListItem`.

```
buildPriceListItem(listLinesId, prn, price, currencyCode, startDateActive, endDateActive): FormGroup {
return this.formBuilder.group({
    listLinesId: listLinesId,
    prn: [prn, Validators.required],
    price: [price, Validators.required],
    currencyCode: [currencyCode, Validators.required],
    startDateActive: [startDateActive, Validators.required],
    endDateActive: [endDateActive, Validators.required]
  }, { validator: startAndEndDateValidator });
}
```

As you can see, I have a `FormGroup` level validator as well as a `FormArray` level validator.

This big process that involves 'mapping' an array (**of large size**) of JSON objects to `FormArray` of `FormGroup`s and running validators for each generated `FormGroup` and complex validation for the whole `FormArray`, makes the browser unresponsive.

Things work fine if the dataset is small.

Please help me with a workaround for this.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the validators ?

Comment: @c69 I want the validators. Even if I remove the validators, the time the page stays unresponsive gets just reduced.

Comment: Ok.. if you say that page is slow even without validators - how many elements total ? What code you use to generate inner formGroups ? The one you showed - looks innocent.

Comment: The `buildPriceListItem` function generates and returns elements (`FormGroup`s) that are the members of the `FormArray`. Number of elements in total? - say 600.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to show all of the data to the user or need to process it all at once: Limit the data and load it in chunks. Maybe with a filter (backend/frontend).

If this is not enough or not a solution, you could separate this as a process in a webworker, so your UI proceeds responsive.

Comment: `Worker` seems to be my solution as I don't wanna paginate the array due to some business constraints. Any insights on using a worker with `Angular`?

Comment: Just read some blog posts, seems to work fine: https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-with-web-workers-step-by-step-dc11d5872135